# Mung bean sprouts developed a slight purple color on day 3?

Tags: beans, sprouting

I've been sprouting my beans for three days now; yesterday I noticed some had developed a slight purple coloration while rinsing them, photo attached. One of them even went blue-ish, but there is no brown or signs of mold. Is this normal or should I worry?

Here's a picture of the sprouts:

[image: Here's a pic of the sprouts]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sprouts developing a purple tinge is fine, it's a sign that they were exposed to light - they will even start turning green if they recieve more light.

This is like with white asparagus: As long as the stalks remain completely covered in the soil, they stay white. If they start to break through the surface, they develop a purple tinge in a very short time.

See the picture below:
Some stalks are still white, some slighltly purple.

[image: ASPARAGUS]

Comment: But there's nothing wrong with eating green-ed sprouts, or is there?

Comment: No, they are just fine. Give them another day or two, then enjoy them.